# In IOS where does the grey background colors of a selected UITableViewCell comes from?

Tags: ios, ios8, uitableview

As you can see on this small gif, when you select a cell inside a table view, the background colors become grey.

[image: demo]
I would like to get this color programmatically.

I've tried inside my UITableViewCell subclass to access :

```
self.selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor
```

and

```
self.backgroundView?.backgroundColor
```

But I get a blue color (like in older version of iOS)

[image: demo2]

I've lookup in the debuging view hierarchy to find it out but without success.

In advance thanks for your help!

Regards,
Eric

[Edit]
What I'm trying here is to get the background color from my cell to set it on a subview inside my cell.

Comment: override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
  //access the cell's color here
}

Comment: Thanks @Vig. I've tried to to override that function in my UITableViewDelegate unfortunately I still get the blue color instead of the grey one.

Comment: Are you looking to get the color or set the color?

Comment: @Vig I'm looking to get the color so I can set it to a subview of my cell.

Comment: and what is your current selection color you are seeing on the simulator?

Comment: You have to set cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray and then access the color to get the gray color. Otherwise your cell has default blue color selection style.

Comment: @Vig I've already set the selectionStyle to UITableViewCellSelectionsStyle.Gray

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74845/discussion-between-eric-and-vig).

Answer (score 1):

in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

do

```
cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];

// CHoose the color you want to show when cell is selected
bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0f/255.0f green:250.0f/255.0f blue:240.0f/255.0f alpha:0.1f];

bgColorView.layer.cornerRadius = -17;
bgColorView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
[cell setSelectedBackgroundView:bgColorView];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kreuzberg. I'm already able to change the color as I wan't when I'm hardcoding the color. What I'm trying here is to retrieve the UIColor so I don't need to hardcode it.

Answer (score 0):

UITableViewCell have property selectionStyle. Look in to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've already took a look at selectionStyle. But it's an enum. I'll give me which selectionStyle is used. But what I'm looking for is a UIColor(). I'm not sure I can or how I can get that from the selectionStyle.